# Android SQLiteDatabase - Listview and database mismatch ID after deleting value from the database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, listview

Hello every one I am new to android SQLiteDatabase. I am following tutorial from this site [ORIGINAL CODE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) . The below code is about Add, update, Delete name from the database.

Everything is working fine. I am able to add, update and delete name from the database.

Problem: 
For example I added 4 names.

```
ID name 
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
```

when I delete A it get deleted from the listview and database. It is updated in listview. 
Now the database looks like this

```
ID name 
1  null
2   B
3   C
4   D
```

And Listview looks like this

```
B
C
D
```

So when I click on B to delete or edit it shows nothing in my edit and delete view but when I click on C it shows me B in delete view.

I gone through all the solutions which is available in stackoverflow and I know it is repeated questions but is there any solution for this example.
I want when I click on B it should show B not null and when I click on C it should show C, After deleting A.

NOTE: Can any one fix the code please. I am very sure there are many developers who are looking for to fix this issue. Specially beginners like me. It would be great help.Thank you in advance.

**DBHelper**

```
    public Integer deleteContact (Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("contacts",
            "id = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts() {

    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    //hp = new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

**devicedetailsActivity**

```
public class devicedetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "MESSAGE";
    private ListView obj;
    DBHelper mydb;
    ArrayList array_list ;
    public ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.devicedetails_layout);
        mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    }
    public void onResume() {

        refreshList();
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void refreshList() {
        array_list = mydb.getAllCotacts();
        arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

        obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        obj.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;

                Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                dataBundle.putInt("id", 0);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(dataBundle);

                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.item2: dataBundle = new Bundle();
                dataBundle.putInt("id", 0);
                 intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**DetailsActivity**

```
    public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DBHelper mydb ;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    TextView name ;
    int id_To_Update = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        mydb = new DBHelper(this);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras !=null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if(Value>0){
                //means this is the view part not the add contact part.
                Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
                if(rs.moveToFirst()) {
                    id_To_Update = Value;
                    rs.moveToFirst();
                    String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
                    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                    b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    name.setText((CharSequence)nam);
                    name.setFocusable(false);
                    name.setClickable(false);
                }
                if (!rs.isClosed())  {
                    rs.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras !=null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if(Value>0){
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_contact, menu);
            } else{
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.back, menu);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Edit_Contact:
                Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                name.setEnabled(true);
                name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                name.setClickable(true);
                return true;

            case R.id.Delete_Contact:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteContact)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                mydb.deleteContact(id_To_Update);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),devicedetailsActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })

                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog d = builder.create();
                d.setTitle("Are you sure");
                d.show();
                return true;
            case R.id.back:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),devicedetailsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return  true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    public void run(View view) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras !=null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if(Value>0){
                if(mydb.updateContact(id_To_Update,name.getText().toString()
                        )){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),devicedetailsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else{
                if(mydb.insertContact(name.getText().toString())){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),devicedetailsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do not use `ArrayAdapter`, instead use `SimpleCursorAdapter` - read carefully MikeT's excellent answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Issue

The 3rd argument (arg2) to the onItemClickListener is the position  (as will be the 4th unless you use a Cursor Adapter).

The **position** will never equate to the **id** (unless you forced id's to have certain values) that is because the first item has a position of 0. The id of the first row will be 1. If you start deleting rows then life gets more complicated as you have found.

### Soultions (in theory)

What you have to do is get the correct **id**.

You could use a complimentary ArrayList of Longs `ArrayList<Long>` or an Array of longs `long[]` (you need two methods to build the `ArrayList<String>` and the `ArrayList<long>` or `long[]`). However if you used a filter then this may then also be out of sync. **As such this method is not really recommended.**

You could use a Cursor Adapter and a Cursor as the source for the ListView and then the 4th parameter would be the id (requires that a column named **_id** which should be the row's **id**). **I'd Recommended using Cursors as there is no need for intermediate objects**

You could use an ArrayList of objects `ArrayList<your_object>`, in which case the object would have at least two members **id** and **name**. You could then use the Adapter's `getItem(arg2)` method to retrieve the object and then get the **id** from the object.

### Working Example with 2 Solutions

The following is code for an App that displays 3 Listviews the first sourced by a String ArrayList (what you currently have), the second by an  object ArrayList (an appropriate object i.e. a MyTableObject ArrayList) and the third via a Cursor. The data displayed being identical.

Clicking on an item displays the values that can be obtained (**the values that could be passed to a deletion**).

- the first ListView only the position can be obtained and that is displayed (as if it were the ID),
- the second ListView shows the ID obtained from the object and the ID obtained from the position (they will not match)
- the 3rd ListView shows the ID obtained via the Cursor (equivalent to the object) and the ID obtained from the 4th parameter, they always match.
- **Note each time the App is run more data will be added.**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;

    ListView mListView01,mListVeiw02,mListView03;

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapterStringArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<MyTableObject> mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapterCursor;

    ArrayList<String> mMyTableListAsStrings;
    ArrayList<MyTableObject> mMyTableAsObjects;
    Cursor mMyTableListAsCursor;

    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        mListView01 = this.findViewById(R.id.listview01);
        mListVeiw02 = this.findViewById(R.id.listview02);
        mListView03 = this.findViewById(R.id.listview03);

        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Fred");
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Bert");
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Harry");
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Fred");

        //String Array List
        mMyTableListAsStrings = mDBHlpr.getAllAsStringArrayList();
        mAdapterStringArrayList = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mMyTableListAsStrings
        );
        mListView01.setAdapter(mAdapterStringArrayList);


        //Object Array List
        mMyTableAsObjects = mDBHlpr.getAllAsMyTableObjectArrayList();
        mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mMyTableAsObjects
        );
        mListVeiw02.setAdapter(mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList);

        // Cursor
        mMyTableListAsCursor = mDBHlpr.getAllAsCursor();
        mAdapterCursor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mMyTableListAsCursor,
                new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COL_MYTABLE_NAME},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0
        );
        mListView03.setAdapter(mAdapterCursor);


        mListView01.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                String name = mAdapterStringArrayList.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(
                        mContext,
                        "Name is " + name  +
                                ". ID is " + String.valueOf(id) +
                                " (note may not match)",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
        });

        mListVeiw02.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                MyTableObject mytable = mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList.getItem(position);
                String name = mytable.getName();
                long id_in_object = mytable.getId();
                Toast.makeText(
                        mContext,
                        "Name is " + name  +
                                ". ID from object is " + String.valueOf(id_in_object) +
                                ". ID from adapter is " + String.valueOf(id),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
        });

        mListView03.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor csr = mAdapterCursor.getCursor(); // already positioned
                String name = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_MYTABLE_NAME));
                long id_in_cursor = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COl_MYTABLE_ID));
                Toast.makeText(
                        mContext,
                        "Name is " + name  +
                                ". ID from object is " + String.valueOf(id_in_cursor) +
                                ". ID from adapter is " + String.valueOf(id),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TB_MYTABLE = "mytable";
    public static final String COl_MYTABLE_ID = BaseColumns._ID; //<<<< use standard android id column name
    public static final String COL_MYTABLE_NAME = "_name";

    private static final String mytable_crtsql =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_MYTABLE +
                    "(" +
                    COl_MYTABLE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    COL_MYTABLE_NAME + " TEXT " +
                    ")";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(mytable_crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addRow(String name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_MYTABLE_NAME,name);
        return mDB.insert(TB_MYTABLE,null,cv);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllAsStringArrayList() {
        ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(
                TB_MYTABLE,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_MYTABLE_NAME)));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public ArrayList<MyTableObject> getAllAsMyTableObjectArrayList() {
        ArrayList<MyTableObject> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(
                TB_MYTABLE,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(new MyTableObject(
                    csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_MYTABLE_ID)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_MYTABLE_NAME))
                    )
            );
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public Cursor getAllAsCursor() {
        return mDB.query(
                TB_MYTABLE,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
    }
}
```

**MyTableObject.java**

```
public class MyTableObject {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    public MyTableObject(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    /*
        NOTE toString method returns just the name
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ArrayList-String"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ArrayList-object"
            />
        <TextView
            android:text="Cursor"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffaaaa">
        </ListView>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffaaffaa">
        </ListView>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview03"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffaaaaff">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### Working Example Updated with Deletion Added

The following is the above but with the ability to delete rows on a longclick (only for the 2nd and 3rd ListView).

The MainActivity has been changed to

- include OnItemLongClick listeners for the 2nd and 3rd ListViews

  - The newly added `delete` method is invoked with the id passed
  - The `refreshAllListViews` is then called to refresh all the ListViews
- **Note** There is no reliable way to delete from the 1st ListView

**The changed MainActivity.java** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;

    ListView mListView01,mListVeiw02,mListView03;

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapterStringArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<MyTableObject> mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapterCursor;

    ArrayList<String> mMyTableListAsStrings;
    ArrayList<MyTableObject> mMyTableAsObjects;
    Cursor mMyTableListAsCursor;

    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        mListView01 = this.findViewById(R.id.listview01);
        mListVeiw02 = this.findViewById(R.id.listview02);
        mListView03 = this.findViewById(R.id.listview03);

        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Fred");
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Bert");
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Harry");
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Fred");

        //String Array List
        mMyTableListAsStrings = mDBHlpr.getAllAsStringArrayList();
        mAdapterStringArrayList = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mMyTableListAsStrings
        );
        mListView01.setAdapter(mAdapterStringArrayList);


        //Object Array List
        mMyTableAsObjects = mDBHlpr.getAllAsMyTableObjectArrayList();
        mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mMyTableAsObjects
        );
        mListVeiw02.setAdapter(mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList);

        // Cursor
        mMyTableListAsCursor = mDBHlpr.getAllAsCursor();
        mAdapterCursor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mMyTableListAsCursor,
                new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COL_MYTABLE_NAME},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0
        );
        mListView03.setAdapter(mAdapterCursor);


        mListView01.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                String name = mAdapterStringArrayList.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(
                        mContext,
                        "Name is " + name  +
                                ". ID is " + String.valueOf(id) +
                                " (note may not match)",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
        });

        mListVeiw02.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                MyTableObject mytable = mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList.getItem(position);
                String name = mytable.getName();
                long id_in_object = mytable.getId();
                Toast.makeText(
                        mContext,
                        "Name is " + name  +
                                ". ID from object is " + String.valueOf(id_in_object) +
                                ". ID from adapter is " + String.valueOf(id),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
        });
        mListVeiw02.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                mDBHlpr.delete(mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList.getItem(i).getId());
                refreshAllListViews();
                return true;
            }
        });

        mListView03.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor csr = mAdapterCursor.getCursor(); // already positioned
                String name = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_MYTABLE_NAME));
                long id_in_cursor = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COl_MYTABLE_ID));
                Toast.makeText(
                        mContext,
                        "Name is " + name  +
                                ". ID from object is " + String.valueOf(id_in_cursor) +
                                ". ID from adapter is " + String.valueOf(id),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
        });
        mListView03.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                mDBHlpr.delete(l);
                refreshAllListViews();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void refreshAllListViews() {
        mMyTableListAsStrings.clear();
        ArrayList<String> newStringArray = mDBHlpr.getAllAsStringArrayList();
        mMyTableListAsStrings.addAll(newStringArray);
        mAdapterStringArrayList.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mMyTableAsObjects.clear();
        ArrayList<MyTableObject> newObjectArray = mDBHlpr.getAllAsMyTableObjectArrayList();
        mMyTableAsObjects.addAll(newObjectArray);
        mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mMyTableListAsCursor = mDBHlpr.getAllAsCursor();
        mAdapterCursor.swapCursor(mMyTableListAsCursor);
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHelper.java** has been changed to include a new method to delete a row according to the **id**

i.e. the following method has been added :-

```
public int delete(long id) {
    String whereclause = COl_MYTABLE_ID + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
    return mDB.delete(TB_MYTABLE,whereclause,whereargs);
}
```

Comment: Well elaborate.

Comment: @MikeT Thank you so so much. Great explanation. Really helpful. I fixed my issue with `SimpleCursorAdapter `:-) ..